# All items of a list gets updated

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app for android using flutter. However, during this course, some unexpected things happens which I could not figure out. I have two class in my model which are as follows.

```
class Term {
  final String type;
  String value;

  Term({required this.type, required this.value});
}

class CalcData {
  final List<Term> expression;
  final String result;

  const CalcData(this.expression, this.result);
}
```

and whenever a button gets tapped, a new `CalcData` should be added to `List<CalcData> _history`. However when the button gets tapped, a new `CalcData` is added to `_history`, but at the same time the `expression` of all other existing `CalcData` in `_history` gets updated to recent `expression`, even though the `result` remains unaltered.

**[updated]** 
*`model.dart`*

```
class Term {
  final String type;
  String value;

  Term({required this.type, required this.value});
}

class CalcData {
  final List<Term> expression;
  final String result;

  const CalcData(this.expression, this.result);
}
```

*`service.dart`*

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'model.dart';

class ContentService extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Term> _terms = [];
  String? _result;
  bool _resultFocused = false;
  List<CalcData> _history = [];

  List<Term> get terms => _terms;
  String? get result => _result;
  bool get resultFocused => _resultFocused;
  List<CalcData> get history => _history;

  void addTerm(Term term) => _terms.add(term);
  void updateTerm(Term term, String newValue) => term.value += newValue;
  void evaluteResult() => _result = _terms.map((term) => term.value).toList().join();

  void tapNumbers(String value) {
    if (_resultFocused && _terms.isNotEmpty && _result != null) {
      CalcData __data = CalcData(_terms, _result!);
      _history = [..._history, __data];

      _terms.clear();
      _result = null;

      _resultFocused = false;
    }

    if (_terms.isEmpty)
      this.addTerm(Term(type: 'Numeric', value: value));
    else
      this.updateTerm(_terms.last, value);

    this.evaluteResult();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void confirm() {
    _resultFocused = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

*`main.dart`*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'model.dart';
import 'service.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider<ContentService>(
          create: (context) => ContentService(),
          child: Contents(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Contents extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ContentService service = Provider.of<ContentService>(context, listen: false);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: _HistoryScreen(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          _EditScreen(),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => service.tapNumbers('1'), child: Text('1')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => service.tapNumbers('2'), child: Text('2')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => service.tapNumbers('3'), child: Text('3')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => service.tapNumbers('4'), child: Text('4')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => service.confirm(), child: Icon(Icons.done)),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _HistoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Selector<ContentService, List<CalcData>>(
      selector: (context, service) => service.history,
      builder: (context, data, _) => ListView.separated(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: data[index].expression.map((exp) => Text(exp.value)).toList(),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(data[index].result),
        ),
        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _EditScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ContentService>(
      builder: (context, service, _) => Wrap(
        children: service.terms.map((term) {
          return Text(
            term.value,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**How it should behave ?**
Every time a number button is tapped, the value merged with existing value should appear on screen. When the confirm button is tapped, the `_resultFocused` should be set to `true`, although nothing should happen visually. Now if a number button is tapped after that, the existing value, without any update, should be added to `_history` and the new value should appear on screen.

**How it is behaving..**
Every time a number button is tapped, the value merged with existing value appears on screen, and also on confirmation, the `_resultFocused` is set to `true`. However, when a number button is tapped after that, the existing value gets partially updated (`CalcData.expression` get updated while `CalcData.result` remains unaltered) and added to the `_history`.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Specifically, share the code where you create and add a new `CalcData`.

Comment: code shared.. waiting for response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `_terms.clear()` to `_terms = []`, and now it is working. Although still wondering what is wrong with `_terms.clear()`